# Count the number of elements during the selected time period

Tags: r, dplyr

I have select the activities that are occurs between 30 min time period. I want to count the number of activities each 30 min range

```
node <- c("ABC","ABC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC")

activity <-c("LOSS_OF_MULTIPLEX_SECTION-OMS_A","LOSS_OF_MULTIPLEX_SECTION-OMS_A","NODE_ISOLATION","NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF","NODE_ISOLATION","LOSS_OF_MULTIPLEX_SECTION-OMS_A","NODE_ISOLATION","NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF","NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF", "UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A","UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A","UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A") 

e <-c("2020-05-09 04:50:42","2020-05-09 06:16:54","2020-05-08 16:11:58","2020-05-08 16:11:58","2020-05-08 16:30:07","2020-05-09 03:00:08","2020-05-09 03:08:08","2020-05-09 03:28:08","2020-05-09 13:08:08","2020-05-09 13:10:08","2020-05-09 13:28:08","2020-05-09 14:28:08")

df <- data.frame(node, activity, e)
df
```

```
library(dplyr)

tlead <- . %>% lead(., order_by = ., default = max(.) + 1801) # 1801 secs
tlag <- . %>% lag(., order_by = ., default = min(.) - 1801)

df %>% 
  mutate(e = as.POSIXct(e, tz = "")) %>% 
  group_by(node) %>% 
  filter(e - tlag(e) <= as.difftime("00:30:00") | tlead(e) - e <= as.difftime("00:30:00"))
```

output for above code is

```
node <- c("ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC")

activity <-c("NODE_ISOLATION","NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF","NODE_ISOLATION","LOSS_OF_MULTIPLEX_SECTION-OMS_A","NODE_ISOLATION","NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF","NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF", "UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A","UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A") 

e <-c("2020-05-08 16:11:58","2020-05-08 16:11:58","2020-05-08 16:30:07","2020-05-09 03:00:08","2020-05-09 03:08:08","2020-05-09 03:28:08","2020-05-09 13:08:08","2020-05-09 13:10:08","2020-05-09 13:28:08")

df1 <- data.frame(node, activity, e)
df1
```

Now I try to combine those activities that are in selected 30min time and desired output is follow

```
node <- c("ABCC","ABCC","ABCC")

activity <-c("NODE_ISOLATION,NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF,NODE_ISOLATION","LOSS_OF_MULTIPLEX_SECTION-OMS_A,NODE_ISOLATION,NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF","NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF,UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A,UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A") 

cnt <- c(3,3,3)
df1 <- data.frame(node, activity, cnt)
df1
```

Comment: 30 mins from the first time in your data or rounded off to nearest 30th minute of an hour?

Answer (score 0):

I am not completly sure what you want but here is maybe what you are interested. The
`POSIXlt` class is in seconds as you observe:

```r
as.numeric(as.POSIXlt("1970-01-01 01:00:00")) # time zero
#R> [1] 0
as.numeric(as.POSIXlt("1970-01-01 01:00:01")) # times are in seconds
#R> [1] 1
```

Thus, you can split time into 30 minutes interval like this:

```r
# create interval variable
df <- within(df, {
  num_time <- as.numeric(as.POSIXlt(e))
  interval <- num_time %/% 1800
  interval <- as.POSIXct(interval * 1800, origin = "1970-01-01")
})

# now do 
with(df, tapply(node, list(node, interval), length, default = 0L))
#R>      2020-05-08 16:00:00 2020-05-08 16:30:00 2020-05-09 03:00:00 2020-05-09 04:30:00
#R> ABC                    0                   0                   0                   1
#R> ABCC                   2                   1                   3                   0
#R>      2020-05-09 06:00:00 2020-05-09 13:00:00 2020-05-09 14:00:00
#R> ABC                    1                   0                   0
#R> ABCC                   0                   3                   1

# or
tapply(df$interval, df$node, function(x) tapply(x, x, length))
#R> $ABC
#R> 2020-05-09 04:30:00 2020-05-09 06:00:00 
#R>                   1                   1 
#R> 
#R> $ABCC
#R> 2020-05-08 16:00:00 2020-05-08 16:30:00 2020-05-09 03:00:00 2020-05-09 13:00:00 
#R>                   2                   1                   3                   3 
#R> 2020-05-09 14:00:00 
#R>                   1
```

This seems to match the data:

```r
df[, c("node", "e")]
#R>    node                   e
#R> 1   ABC 2020-05-09 04:50:42
#R> 2   ABC 2020-05-09 06:16:54
#R> 3  ABCC 2020-05-08 16:11:58
#R> 4  ABCC 2020-05-08 16:11:58
#R> 5  ABCC 2020-05-08 16:30:07
#R> 6  ABCC 2020-05-09 03:00:08
#R> 7  ABCC 2020-05-09 03:08:08
#R> 8  ABCC 2020-05-09 03:28:08
#R> 9  ABCC 2020-05-09 13:08:08
#R> 10 ABCC 2020-05-09 13:10:08
#R> 11 ABCC 2020-05-09 13:28:08
#R> 12 ABCC 2020-05-09 14:28:08
```

Comment: Thank you for your consideration and I have updated the question, I hope now its clear.